# why d3 lines work with one js object but do not with another js object?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

So the D3 code is as follows:

The D3 code in both cases is

```
  msBars = svgContainer.selectAll('line')
                    .data(jsonFragmentIons)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")

  msBarAttributes = msBars
                     .attr("x1", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                     .attr("y1", h - padding)
                     .attr("x2", (d) -> return xScale(d.m_mz) )
                     .attr("y2", (d) -> return h - yScale(d.m_intensity) )
                     .attr("stroke-width", 1.2)
                     .attr("stroke", (d) -> return d.color)
```

where the scaling functions are previously defined.
Again all the d3 code is one, the json obect is different. To illustrate this I created this two jsfiddles where the only different thing is the json object.

Here,

**http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/6/**

the code seems to work ok, all the lines are drawn.

But if I change the json object, here:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/7/**

D3 does not draw one line per datum in the json object...
This is puzzling me. Why could this be happening?
The only thing I can think of is the different scale of the mz_intensity attribute , but, then why one line is drawn ok but no the rest?

Comment: Please note that your problem has **nothing** whatsoever to do with JSON. In both of your examples, you have an array of object. Even if you get the data originally as JSON, it's irrelevant to the problem, since you have regular JS objects/arrays after the JSON is parsed. See also [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: and also, I forgot to mention, the text label is added correctly only sometimes...

Comment: very interesting @FelixKling , I guess it is a pretty common misconception. I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Trying simpler things, it would seem jsfiddle doesn't like mixing CoffeScript and d3.js.

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with jsfiddle. It shows exactly the same thing as my chrome browser with my rails setup (WEBrick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing the axes before adding the lines and labels. By doing `.selectAll("line")` and `.selectAll("text")`, you're selecting the existing DOM elements that the axis component added. Then you're matching data to it and therefore your `.enter()` selection doesn't contain what you suppose.

This problem is also present in the "working" jsfiddle, but less prominent as there are more data items. To fix, either add the axes at the end, or add a distinguishing class to the elements you add manually (e.g. `bar`) that you can use when selecting. Example that implements the latter solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/8/).

Comment: Hey, great diagnosis and explanation of the problem! I chose to add a class like so: `.selectAll('line.peak')` and `.selectAll('text.peak_label')` . It works perfectly fine, but in the generated html, lines and labels do not appear to have the stated classes (?)

Comment: You need to add those classes as well -- `.attr("class", "peak")` (see the linked jsfiddle).